# How can i use latin characters in a hebrew sentence

Tags: xml, actionscript, hebrew, data-storage

Currently we are extending the website for a coffee retailer. The whole page is in Flash and content is supplied by external XML-Files. However, the company expanded to Israel and therefore we are working on a hebrew version of the page (different charset and right-to-left). This works to 80% fine but sometimes we have sentences which contain latin nouns.

On one page the **second sentence** should look like this:
http://jtdev.at/transfer/hebrew.png (according to our israeli partner)

This is my XML:

```
<card>UTZ CERTIFIED</card>
<title>UTZ CERTIFIED</title>
<text>קרמסו מציעה לא רק קפה נפלא כוס אחרי כוס, אלא גם את הסטנדרטים הגבוהים ביותר של גידול&#x202B;.&#x202C;
  קרמסו הינה יצרנית הקפסולות הראשונה בעולם ולקבל את אישור ארגון ה ‪&#‬x202B‪;‬2010 UTZ‪&#‬x202C‪;‬,ובכך להבטיח‪&#‬x202B‪;.&#‬x202C‪;‬
   ארגון זה מכליל את מגדלי הקפה ואת הטבע כחלקים חשובים מתהליך שלם&#x202B;.&#x202C;
</text>
```

This is the actual output:
http://jtdev.at/transfer/out.png

No matter what I do, it always shows up as "UTZ 2010" instead of "2010 UTZ"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your xsl(t) file

Comment: How do you translate your xml file to that on the screenshots? Isn't that `HTML`? Or do you use `CSS`?

Comment: No, the screenshot was taken from a SWF-file which uses XML as external content storage. The XML gets parsed by Actionscript and the contents are used for filling textfields in the SWF.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed that point with flash. I don't know flash so good that I could help you. But I will retag your question.

Comment: What happens if you break the line between "UTZ" and "2010" ? without adding a special newline character, just to verify the order of the "UTZ 2010" components? It seems that the problem is a combination of [rightToLeft paragraph] + [LeftToRight latin] + [LeftToRight number] + [maybe the comma sign , , , is also involved]

Comment: I just found a way. I posted it as update on my question. I'm not yet allowed to answer it myswlf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, I found a way how it looks right!!

In the RTL-Embedding `&#x202B; ... &#x202C;` i just put a LTR-Embedding `&#x202A; ... &#x202C;` with my latin characters.

My new XML:

```
<card>UTZ CERTIFIED</card>
<title>UTZ CERTIFIED</title>
<text>קרמסו מציעה לא רק קפה נפלא כוס אחרי כוס, אלא גם את הסטנדרטים הגבוהים ביותר של גידול&#x202B;.&#x202C;
  קרמסו הינה יצרנית הקפסולות הראשונה בעולם ולקבל את אישור ארגון ה ‪&#‬x202B‪;&#‬x202A‪;‬2010 UTZ‪&#‬x202C‪;&#‬x202C‪;‬ ,ובכך להבטיח‪&#‬x202B‪;.&#‬x202C‪;‬
   ארגון זה מכליל את מגדלי הקפה ואת הטבע כחלקים חשובים מתהליך שלם&#x202B;.&#x202C;
</text>
```